Реализация "растягивания" мышкой 3d модели в 3d редакторе
Пишу небольшой редактор 3d моделек, который поддерживает стандартные функции (перемещение 3d модели, регулирование размера, загрузка текстуры).
Представим себе ситуацию: человек загрузил, к примеру, модель черепа, плюс текстура лица. Ему теперь хочется, скажем, немного вытянуть подбородок. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы можно было выбрать подбородок мышкой и начать его "вытягивать". При этом текстура должна нормально сидеть на черепе, чтобы всё красиво смотрелось. Как вообще реализовать данную функцию? Под этим имею в виду, как можно выбрать точку на модели, за нее "потянуть" mesh с текстурой и чтобы эта текстура не съезжала? То есть в целом, как такую технологию реализовать, очень желательно стандартными алгоритмами без привлечения ai.

Полезно подумать о граничных случаях. Вот вы потянули подбородок и вытянули его на 100 метров. Текстура точно не должна съезжать? А как должна себя повести?

Было бы вообще хорошо иллюстрировать желаемое поведение примером (парой картинок).

Да, определенно, граничные случаи будут. Допустим, вообще будет ползунок, которым можно регулировать растяжение.

Небольшие растяжения обычно просто морфами делают (см. morph target), и при небольших растяжениях текстуры еще не сильно заметно тянутся.

Спасибо, а можно ли этот morphing target добавить к mesh определённого типа (пусть только лица)? Но mesh лица может быть любой загруженный. Можно ли как то определить morphing и применять на произвольное лицо? (mesh вроде как не сильно отличается, все таки все mesh черепа примерно похожи)

В чистом виде - нет. Однако, если вы уверены, что подбородок будет всегда в определенном месте, то можете попробовать процедерно это место вытягивать (например, сферу с радиусом Н и плавным снижением силы в зависимости от расстояния от центра). Или же потребовать, чтобы у моделей была как-то размечена область подбородка (например, картой весов).

Хорошо, то есть в итоге можно, скажем, задать скелет в каком-нибудь blender, а потом в моем редакторе уже вручную быстро раскидать "кости" на разные части mesha и закрепить, чтобы кости были привязаны к модели?

Да. Примерно так.

AI тут вообще не причем (по крайней мере на ближайшие лет 5).
Полезно подумать о граничных случаях. Вот вы потянули подбородок и вытянули его на 100 метров. Текстура точно не должна съезжать? А как должна себя повести?
Небольшие растяжения обычно просто морфами делают (см. morph target), и при небольших растяжениях текстуры еще не сильно заметно тянутся.
Если вы уверены, что подбородок будет всегда в определенном месте, то можете попробовать процедерно это место вытягивать (например, сферу с радиусом Н и плавным снижением силы в зависимости от расстояния от центра).
Или же потребовать, чтобы у моделей была как-то размечена область подбородка (например, картой весов). Тогда это будет по сути скелетная анимация, где вытягивание подбородка - это вытягивание кости подбородка.
Чтобы затяжки текстуры были не так заметны - посмотрите в сторону detail map (микротекстур). Также в целом может быть интересен подход в процедурными текстурами (вместо или вместе с UV), но тут уже сильно от модели зависит.
